# How many different topology exist on A, where is |A| = n

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics

So the question is "How many different topologies exist on A union, where is |A| = n"?

Comment: What is "$A$ union"?

Comment: This is an open problem.  See, eg, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8970/number-of-valid-topologies-on-a-finite-set-of-n-elements